# Can I replace three out of four rubber brake hoses with stainless braided brake hoses?

Tags: brakes

Last night I started to replaced the rubber brake hoses on my car with stainless steel braided brake hoses. To my dismay, I discovered that the flare plug bolt on the hard brake line behind the rear driver side brake hose is completely rounded off so I cannot remove it.

I also replaced all the pads and rotors, plus the rear calipers, and I will be doing a full brake fluid refill and bleed before driving... but I don't have time to wait for a replacement flare plug.

Is it a bad idea to run with three braided brake hoses and one rubber brake hose for a little while? Will the difference in hydraulic pressure be significant enough to cause uneven braking or wear in the short term?

Comment: steel braided hoses still have rubber inside, that is just the covering. "what is that thin metal brake line called" just that a brake line.

Comment: @Moab thank you! but the covering restricts expansion, delivering more hydraulic pressure to the piston. right? i guess my question is whether that difference in hydraulic pressure is enough to cause uneven braking or pad wear.

Comment: Steel braiding is more for looks and resistance from heat and abrasion.

Comment: Pressure will equalize in a brake hydraulic system, only air in the system can cause that type of issue.

Comment: Do you have ABS ? If you do, it will balance the brakes via the speed sensor input to the ABS control module. However this is obviously not ideal but still driveable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what type of steel braided hose you are replacing with, should be with PTFE inner liner hose and it has a different rate of expansion than factory hoses so you need to replace all of the hoses at the same time.

Also, steel braided hose are not just for look and abrasion, they limit the amount of expansion and protect the hose from cuts.